# Maven Plugin to stop execution without thowing MojoExecutionException

Tags: java, maven, maven-2

I am writing a maven plugin. Inside the execute() function I need to instantiate another class and monitor for certain activities. When a certain condition is met I want to cancel the execution of the maven process but I cannot throw just an exception as the context will be different. Here is a bit of code which illustrates what I mean:

```
public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException {
  new AnotherClass() {
    void monitorForSomething() {
      // cancel execution here
    }
  }.start();
}
```

As far as I can tell, the only way to flag an error in order to cancel a build is to raise an Exception but that will be useless if raised from this inner class as the exception wont escalate via the start() function. Is there anything else I can use apart from using threads which will be cumbersome to say at least? It will been very nice if there is a way to stop the build via a method instead of just throwing an exception.

Comment: I would surround the inner class with try-catch block to see which kind of exception has been raised. But if this means something has gone wrong you have to raise an exception to Maven which means to break the build otherwise it doesn't make sense.

Comment: The start method is not going to raise anything because all exceptions are trapped. I wonder if it is possible to raise exception from the inner class without actually raising an exception.